# DynamoDB change in throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, throughput

I am using DynamoDB and I want to change throughput of Dynamo tables.

Will throughput will be changed instantly or it will take some time to be affected completely?

I tried searching for the answer but could not find it even on the Amazon website.

If I change a throughput for table, how much time it will to get affected?

Answer (score 2):

It won't be instantaneous. From my experience it depends greatly on the size of your current throughput and data. A small table with low throughput (less than a few hundreds of reads or writes ps), it should take a few minutes.

For larger tables with higher through puts I've seen it take a lot longer, as long as 30 minutes. Sorry this is just based on observation, I don't have any formal metrics on it. You can continue to use the table while it's updating.

Answer (score 0):

This document explains how DynamoDB responds to increases in throughput: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Partitions

While this doesn't explain how long it will take to create new partitions, it explains under what circumstances a new partition would actually need to be made.